# Array of Arrays in Angular Class

Tags: arrays, angular, class, arrayofarrays

I'm new to Angular and cant really grasp how to loop through an array inside an array.

I'm trying to achieve same thing as the following C code:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
       printf ("%d", ar[i]);

       for (int j =0; j < 3; j ++ )
       {
           printf ("%d", arre[j]);
       }
       printf ("\n");
   }
```

**But in my case I have a class:**

```
class Arende{
    Id:number 
    Namn :string 
    Status :string 
    RegistreringLista :Registrering[]
}
```

**HTML**:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let arende of arenden">
      <td> {{arende.Id}} </td>
      <td> {{arende.Namn}}</td>
      <td> {{arende.RegistreringLista.xxxx}}</td>
      <td> {{arende.RegistreringLista.yyyy}}</td> 
      <td> {{arende.ResitreringsLista.zzzzz}}</td>
```

I thought that there should be some way to do a:

```
<tr *ngFor="let arende of RegistreingsLista">
```

But that dosen't seem right either ... I have trouble understanding the loop sequence ... How should I set it up?

Comment: The second one : ngFor="let item of arende.RegistreingsLista" ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I solved the problem:

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let arende of arenden">
    <tr *ngFor ="let item of arende.RegistreringLista">
      <td> {{arende.Id}} </td>
      <td> {{arende.Namn}}</td>
      <td> {{item.XXXX}}</td>
      <td> {{item.YYYY}}</td>
      <td> {{item.ZZZZ}}</td>
```

I used "Ng-container" not to screw with the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested `ngFor`s in template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let arende of arenden">
      <td> {{arende.Id}} </td>
      <td> {{arende.Namn}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let inner of arende.RegistreringLista"> {{inner.xxxx}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Problem is that I can't add a ngFor inside a <td> tag. It screws up the HTML. But I saw something called "ng-container" - this may solve it. I'll try some stuff and come back!

Comment: If you provide what you want to achive by creating the table manually in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com), perhaps I can help you further. And yes, `ng-container` is more than helpful in many situtations.